# use claims princpal to access previous authenticated users in Asp.NET web core app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-identity

I am using Azure AD to authenticate users and then use the user and access their claims, access msgraph, and insert data to their calendar.

Now what I want is to save this user so an admin in my asp.net web core app can insert data to this user that exists in the database. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, no, you don't use the other user's claims (**never**). If the admin is an actual AAD admin, they can do things for others. You should read how AAD permissions work.

Comment: Ahh , I understand Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AAD admin can insert data to other users' calendar only when the admin have access to those users' mailboxes.

To archive this, you need to configure that other user gives mailbox permissions "Full Access" to the admin account. And add delegated permission: `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` into the Azure AD app.

See details from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153936/ms-graph-api-calendarview-403-accessdenied-error?answertab=votes#tab-top).